# How to access StorageValue without getter function in tests?

Tags: storage, testing, storagevalue

I have the following StorageValue:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn something)]
pub type Something<T> = StorageValue<_, u32>;
```

With the getter function I can access it like this in my tests:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_something_with_getter() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        System::set_block_number(1);
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), 42));
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(42));
    });
}
```

How do I get the storage value **without** using the getter function? I have tried the following:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_something_without_getter() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        System::set_block_number(1);
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), 42));
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::Something::<Test>::get(), Some(42));
    });
}
```

...and get an error:

```sh
assert_eq!(TemplateModule::Something::<Test>::get(), Some(42));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<pallet::Pallet<mock::Test> as Trait>::Something`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the StorageValue `Something` in your test like so:

```rust
use crate::{mock::*, Error, Event, Something};
```

You can then access it like so:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_something_without_getter() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        System::set_block_number(1);
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), 42));
        assert_eq!(Something::<Test>::get(), Some(42));
        System::assert_last_event(Event::SomethingStored { something: 42, who: 1 }.into());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bruno's answer is okay.

But since you set a getter for that storage `#[pallet::getter(fn something)]`.

The most common and easy way to query this storage is `let something = TemplateModule::something()`.

I recommend you use this way.